# Storyboard error in Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard, uibuilder

I'm working with a client to make a lawyer app.  There is a lot of content so he is helping to create storyboards.  The problem is that when we add any new storyboards the build fails for him but not for me.  We are using Google drive to share the project and he also has Xcode 6.1.1.  He however does not have Yosemite.  Does anyone know why this error would be occurring?

Comment: Too broad of a question. Are you working on the same project at the same time? In general it is better to put the project on GitHub and have him pull a branch.

Comment: If the build fails, there should be a specific error. That error is the answer to your question about why the build fails. If you're not sure where to take it from there, update your question to include the error.